# centering three text boxes in a row according to the middle one in react native

Tags: react-native

I have the following scenario:

```
<View style={{flexDirection:"row",alignitems:"center",justifycontent:"center"}}>
<Icon  width={80}/>
 <Text> 
 {club2.toUpperCase() +
                ' VS ' +
                club1.toUpperCase()}

</Text>
<Icon width={80} />
</View>
```

I want my text to be centered, where the text "VS" is in the center and then club 1 and club 2 to the right and left

Answer (score 1):

Split your text into 3 Text components. Here is an [example](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/text-with-justified-spaces).

```js
<View style={{flexDirection:"row",alignitems:"center",justifycontent:"center"}}>
<Icon  width={80}/>
 <Text> 
 {club2.toUpperCase()}
</Text>
 <Text> 
vs.
</Text>
 <Text> 
 {club1.toUpperCase()}
</Text>               
<Icon width={80} />
</View>
```

Comment: still if the text of club 2 is large the vs goes to the ledt, and and centers the complete view

Comment: In this example -> https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/text-with-fixed-spaces
The text width will always be 1/3 of the view with each.